# Run multiple Ansible playbooks with Python generated var as Argument in one playbook

Tags: variable, ansible

I have python script which generates variables var1 and var2

These variables are used as extra var arguments for Ansible playbooks.

The script variables generated dynamically by python scirpt and playbooks are :

```
cat palybook1.yml ->

- hosts: localhost tasks:
- name: "CV: Publish New Versions" katello_content_view_version: username: "{{ username }}" password: "{{ password }}" server_url: "{{ server_url }}" validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}" organization: "{{ item.org }}" content_view: "{{ item.cv }}" loop: "{{ cvlist }}"

cat palybook2.yml ->

- hosts: localhost tasks:
- name: "CV: Publish New Versions" katello_content_view_version: username: "{{ username }}" password: "{{ password }}" server_url: "{{ server_url }}" validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}" organization: "{{ item.org }}" content_view: "{{ item.cv }}" loop: "{{ cvlist }}"
```

vars1 and vars2 are generated by python script.

```
cat vars1 ->

server_url: "https://www.example1.com" certs: true cvlist:
- { org: 'ORG1',cv: 'cv1' }
- { org: 'ORG2',cv: 'cv2' }
- { org: 'ORG3',cv: 'cv3' }
- { org: 'ORG4',cv: 'cv4' }
- { org: 'ORG5',cv: 'cv5' }

cat vars2 ->

server_url: "https://www.example2.com" certs: true cvlist:
- { org: 'ORG6',cv: 'cv1' }
- { org: 'ORG7',cv: 'cv2' }
- { org: 'ORG8',cv: 'cv3' }
- { org: 'ORG9',cv: 'cv4' }
- { org: 'ORG10',cv: 'cv5' }
```

I need single playbook for below:

```
python3 script.py --host server1.example.com --cycle dev --user user1
--password password1 > vars1 ansible-playbook playbook1.yml --extra-vars "@vars1" --extra-vars "username=user1 password=password1"

python3 script.py --host server2.example.com --cycle dev --user user1
--password password1 > vars2 ansible-playbook playbook2.yml --extra-vars "@vars2" --extra-vars "username=user1 password=password1"
```

As you can see script.py and playbook1/2.yml used twice

I want to use above python script and playbook1/2 in one single playbook.

Can some one let me know if its possible to run python script and multiple playbooks in single playbook

Comment: You could use `local_action` to run the `python` script on your controller machine, then load the vars with `include_vars`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am also looking for running multiple playbooks in single playbook

Comment: That does not make sense. What you most likely really want to do is run multiple *tasks* in a playbook. Refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks

Comment: Yes, I think you are right... Just ignore python script. Just let me know if I can run multiple playbooks in single palybook, if so can you give me an example.